# C# xpath search

Tags: c#, search, xpath

I want to perform a simple search using xpath, this is my XML

[image]

and I want to search the **Time** nodes and return the **Id** node value as the result.

this is my code so far, but i dont get any results

```
XmlNodeList nList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//spEvents:Time[. = '" + eventId + "']/parent::node()/spEvents:Times/spEvents:EventTime/spEvents:Time", xmlnsManager);
```

(Note I am using namespaces)

Thanks
kb

@Jon, my code was working fine with XML to LINQ, as below

```
return (from feed in xmlDoc_Spektrix.Descendants("Event")
                              from et in feed.Element("Times").Elements("EventTime")
                              where Convert.ToDateTime(et.Element("Time").Value).ToShortDateString() == Convert.ToDateTime(dt).ToShortDateString()
                select feed.Element("Id").Value).ToList();
```

but since the namespaces were introduced to the xml feed, my code no longer works, which is why i have had to switch to xpath

this code used to work fine, does anyone know why the above code stops working with namespaces?

Comment: Are you on .Net 2.0 or 3.5+ with access to XLinq?

Comment: We can't see the namespaces in this screenshot. Please post your XML as text.

Comment: Do you have to use xpath? I'd personally use LINQ to XML, which I find easier to understand and get right...

Comment: @Darin the namespace is 
-<Events xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://system.spektrix.com/api/v1/events">

Comment: @sixlettervariables, yes the site is v4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct response to "introducing namespaces broke my query" isn't "change technology" it's "fix the query". This is really easy with LINQ to XML:

```
// I'm guessing the namespace *really* has the http part on...
XNamespace ns = "http://system.spektrix.com/api/v1/events";

return (from feed in xmlDoc_Spektrix.Descendants(ns + "Event")
        from et in feed.Element(ns + "Times").Elements(ns + "EventTime")
        where (DateTime) et.Element(ns + "Time") == dt
        select feed.Element(ns + "Id").Value).ToList();
```

Note the simplified (and more correct in the face of culture changes) conversion of an `XElement` to `DateTime` as well.

Comment: i haven't tested your solution yet, but i am guessing its correct & I wish i posted this hours ago, i cant believe i've missed that one!!! thanks a lot

Comment: @kb: I have yet to see an API which makes XML namespaces as easy to work with as LINQ to XML does :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample, if I understood your question correctly this XPath could work.  If you want to try out XPaths you can open your xml in FireFox with the FirePath plugin.

```
//spEvents:Id[./following-sibling::spEvents:Times/spEvents:time[contains(text(),'yourtimetext')]]
```